# I need filter content of posts accoring to post title and meta value

Tags: wordpress

I have applied following code.

```
$postcode = $_POST['postcode'];
$title = $_POST['term'];

$args = array('post_type' => 'product','meta_query' => array( array( 'key' => 'custom_field_ID_1','value' => $postcode,'compare' => 'LIKE' )));

$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
echo"<pre>";print_r($the_query);echo"</pre>";
```

But showing result according to meta value not for post title. Please let me know solutions...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use post title into `wp_query` by adding this to `functions.php` file:

```
add_filter( 'posts_where', 'yourr_title_func', 10, 2 );
function yourr_title_func( $where, &$the_query )
{
    global $wpdb;
    if ( $search_title = $the_query->get( 'search_title' ) ) {
        $where .= ' AND ' . $wpdb->posts . '.post_title LIKE \'' . esc_sql( like_escape( $search_title ) ) . '%\'';
    }
    return $where;
}
```

now add search_title into your `wp_query` argument

as:

```
$args = array('post_type' => 'product','search_title'   => $title,'meta_query' => array( array( 'key' => 'custom_field_ID_1','value' => $postcode,'compare' => 'LIKE' )));
```

Comment: I have applied this $args = array('post_type' => 'product','search_title' =>$title);
       $thequery = new WP_Query( $args ); but it displays all posts rather then particular one.

Comment: did you add that code in your functions.php file, just update your question with all your effort please...