# WP Query argument to search by post title

Tags: php, wordpress, post, meta

I am trying to filter my posts by post title. I can use the code below perfectly to filter by anything in postmeta, but i want to get results that match against the post title. How do i change this so it searches wp_posts as opposed to wp_postmeta? I want to search purely by title of the post.

```
 'meta_query' => array(
            array(
                'key' => 'post_title',
                'value' => $keywords,
                'compare' => 'LIKE'
            )
        )
```

Comment: A different route, but perhaps https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/11292/how-do-i-get-a-post-page-or-cpt-id-from-a-title-or-slug will help. But as title is not a meta value I don't 'think' your plan would work.

Comment: someone asked the same a while ago, here the approved answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23240346/515114

Answer (score 0):

Not best solution but it works!

```
                $args = array( 
                    'posts_per_page' => 5,
                    's' => $keywords,
                );
```